# how to use cap deploy:set_current_revision

Tags: capistrano3

how to set a capistrano deployment to some particular git previous commit.
There is one command I saw `cap deploy:set_current_revision`
How to pass an argument to this command?
`cap deploy:set_current_revision=`6740ee25...` ? 
How to use this command to set current revision to some previous git commit.

Answer (score 1):

The `deploy:set_current_revision` task merely [fetches the current revision](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/5ccddea330c206bd6f4431f677858719e69cd4aa/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake#L63) from the underlying VCS.

What you would need to do is temporarily (you don't need to commit it unless you are using CI for deployments) add `set :branch, '<REVID>'` to your `deploy.rb`. Then do a normal deployment.